# Change Angular Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to stylize the datepicker for [Angular Boostrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker).

Let's start with the numbers. The first day of the month is 01. The second day is 02. I'd like the first day to be just 1 instead of 01. So I'd like to remove the zero from the numbers 1 through 10.

[Here's a screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFHS5.png)

How do we fix this?

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.datepicker', ['ui.bootstrap.position'])

.constant('datepickerConfig', {
  dayFormat: 'dd',
  monthFormat: 'MMMM',
  yearFormat: 'yyyy',
  dayHeaderFormat: 'EEE',
  dayTitleFormat: 'MMMM yyyy',
  monthTitleFormat: 'yyyy',
  showWeeks: true,
  startingDay: 0,
  yearRange: 20,
  minDate: null,
  maxDate: null
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dayformat="'d'" to have the days displayed as 1-10.

Sample plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4CrN1sfVy7nDq6wzazG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it, BUT... in the same documentation of the Angular Bootstrap Datepicker you'll find **Datepicker Settings** which contains `day-format`. Does that work?

Using your code:

```
.constant('datepickerConfig', {
  dayFormat: 'd', //<--- this one.
  monthFormat: 'MMMM',
  yearFormat: 'yyyy',
  dayHeaderFormat: 'EEE',
  dayTitleFormat: 'MMMM yyyy',
  monthTitleFormat: 'yyyy',
  showWeeks: true,
  startingDay: 0,
  yearRange: 20,
  minDate: null,
  maxDate: null
})
```

Comment: No way... it works! So simple! Hopefully this question helps others with the same question.

Comment: Glad I could help... Don't forget to mark it as correct, green tick next to the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks Jorg! I really appreciate your help. Rajassaur has a plunker example that'll probably be helpful to future viewers, so I'm going to give him the green check. I wish I could give 2 green checks :(